# Weird 502 responses of AWS ELB

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, uwsgi

My website suddenly failed to work this afternoon, responding every request with 502.

I've set up 3 backend instances behind ELB, each with Nginx installed.

At first, I suspected there's something wrong with the backend instances.
But according to status description in the ELB console, all of the instances are in service.

Then I logged in to one of the instances to view the Nginx and app (which is served with `uwsgi`) logs.
What I found out was that there were actually no *5xx* errors there, I could see requests being responded with *200 OK*.

According the [trouble-shooting manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-error-message.html#ts-elb-errorcodes-http502), cause of 502 could be

> Malformed response from the instance or potentially an issue with the load balancer.

I didn't upgrade Nginx or uwsgi, so I don't think my backend has returned malformed responses that ELB couldn't understand.

What else could cause such a situation?

BTW:

I've stopped the `502`s by rolling back to an older version of my application,
and it continues to work even after I redeploy the original version, so I guess it's the *restarting* that works.

Comment: Are you doing HTTPS > ELB > HTTP > nginx?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins No, it's just HTTP.

Comment: And this problem never occurs before.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins might be a bit late, but I'm wondering what caveat's behind the `HTTPS > ELB > HTTP > nginx` thing, as I'm facing a similar problem.